# Concatenating PDFs in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I've got a grip of PDFs that I need to combine into one using PHP. Googling around gives me very little that seems like a reasonable solution. The best thing I can find is to use [exec()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) but that's just ugly. Does anyone know of a more elegant solution that doesn't involve me shelling out all the money on the planet for some non-free lib?

Comment: pdftk is GPL licensed, isn't it?

Comment: @schnaader Aye, I think so. But using exec() is just really inelegant if there is a better solution.

Comment: GPL licensing doesn't "spread" to applications calling GPL-licensed executables in a separate process.

Comment: @Jason And no one said it does... Using exec() is just kinna gross when there are libs available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) AND [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/downloads/) work?

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/

Make sure you have FPDF 1.6.  This is what I tested with.

Regards.

Comment: @neoneye do you have another solution that is PHP driven? pdftk is what I would call a reliable solution using PHP's exec() function.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/) to get access to [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/).

Actually, the homepage of the bridge component has an example with [concatenation of PDFs](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/examples/source.php?source=concat-old.php).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a pure PHP-based solution, because `exec()` is really not that ugly as you might think. As an alternative for `pdftk` you can use [Ghostscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript):

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf header.pdf example.pdf
```